# How to process a very large file in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I am processing a very large file containing raw text in python. The content of the file has the following format:

- each record is separated by `point_separator`
- each field is separated by `field_separator`.

```
new record
field_separator
another field
field_separator
another field
field_separator
another field
field_separator
another field
field_separator
another field
field_separator
another field
field_separator
call
point_separator
new record
field_separator
another field
field_separator
another field
field_separator
another field
field_separator
another field
field_separator
another field
field_separator
another field
field_separator
call
point_separator
new record
field_separator
another field
field_separator
another field
field_separator
another field
field_separator
another field
field_separator
another field
field_separator
another field
field_separator
call
point_separator
```

Previously I was reading the complete file using the python file open API call:

```
with open(file_name, mode='rt', encoding='utf-8') as reader:
    text = reader.read()
    objects = text.strip().split('point_separator')
    ......
```

However, this fails with `MemoryError` when the file is very large i.e. 20GB and I am processing in a machine containing `16GB` RAM.

The problem is I cannot read this file line by line as I have to collect all the fields based on `field_separator` until I see a `point_separator`.

Is there a way so that OS will use paging and it would be handled transparently?

Comment: Is it possible to parse the file line-by-line (e.g. https://cmdlinetips.com/2011/08/three-ways-to-read-a-text-file-line-by-line-in-python/)? How important is it to read more than a single chunk of the file in at a time?

Comment: The problem is I cannot read this file line by line as I have to collect all the fields based on `field_separator` until I see a `point_separator`. And some field can have multiple lines.

Comment: It might still be possible to handle it line by line, manually keeping track of when you last saw a `point_separator` or a `field_separator` to determine how to handle the current line you're on, but I see the issue.

Comment: Read up until the `point_separator`, collecting the fields until you reach it.  Then process the record.  Repeat.  Don't try to collect all of the records in memory at once.

Answer (score 1):

You could write your own [generator function](https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/) that allows you to iterate over the file a record at a time, without ever reading the whole file into memory simultaneously.  For example:

```
def myiter(filename, point_separator):
    with open(filename, mode='rt', encoding='utf-8') as reader:
        text = ''
        while True:
            line = reader.readline()
            if not line:
                break
            if line.strip() == point_separator:
                yield text
                text = ''
            else:
                text += line
    if text:
        yield text


# put in the actual separator values here - tested the version shown 
# in the question using literal "point_separator" and "field_separator" 
point_separator = 'point_separator' 
field_separator = 'field_separator' 
filename = 'test.txt'

for record in myiter(filename, point_separator):
    fields = record.split(field_separator + '\n')
    print(fields)
```

With the example version in the question, this gives:

```
['new record\n', 'another field\n', 'another field\n', 'another field\n', 'another field\n', 'another field\n', 'another field\n', 'call\n']
['new record\n', 'another field\n', 'another field\n', 'another field\n', 'another field\n', 'another field\n', 'another field\n', 'call\n']
['new record\n', 'another field\n', 'another field\n', 'another field\n', 'another field\n', 'another field\n', 'another field\n', 'call\n']
```

You can then strip the newlines as you require (I haven't done this for you already, as I don't know if the fields may be multi-line.)

Also, I haven't done anything special with the "new record" and "call". You could do `print(fields[1:-1])` to exclude these.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `itertools.groupby` to iterate first by everything between "new record" lines and then internally by everything thing between "field_separator" lines. In the outer groupby, `new_record` will be true for all lines holding the text "new record" and `new_record` first goes false, you know you are in the record and do the inner groupby.

```
import itertools

def record_sep(line):
    return line.strip() == "new record"
    
def field_sep(line):
    return line.strip() == "field_separator"
    
records = []

with open('thefile') as fileobj:
    for new_record, record_iter in itertools.groupby(fileobj, record_sep):
        # skip new record group and proceed to field input
        if not new_record:
            record = []
            for new_field, field_iter in itertools.groupby(record_iter, field_sep):
                 # skip field separator group and proceed to value group
                if not new_field:
                    record.append(list(field_iter)) # assuming multiple values in field
            records.append(record)


for record in records:
    print(record)
```

Answer (score 0):

process line by line

```py
objects = []
fields = []
field = ''
with open(file_name, mode='rt', encoding='utf-8') as reader:
    for line in reader:
        line = line.strip()
        if 'point_separator' == line:
            objects.append(fields)
            fields = []
        elif 'field_separator' == line:
            fields.append(field)
            field = ''
        else:
            field += line + '\n'
```